# How to use the inverse cosine (ACOS) in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic

I have a website in Classic ASP with an Access database. I'm using the Google maps API. Now I want to find Companies (from the database) within a radius of 20 km from a given location.

I have found a formular (haversine), but it seems like I can't use `ACOS()`. I get this error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14' 
>   Undefined function 'acos' in expression.

And here is my sql:

```
lat = 56.113517
lng = 10.145928
sql = "SELECT companyId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians(  lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM company HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance"
Set rs = Connect.Execute(sql)
```

I have search and search but I cant find a solution.
Can anybody help?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086749/how-to-do-the-trig-function-arc-cos-acos-in-excel-in-ms-access)

Comment: Yes I have seen this, but I dont kow have to implement it in my site. Could you maybe give me an excample of how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that Access SQL does not have a built-in `ACOS()` function. If you were running your query in Access itself then you could create your own `ACOS()` function in VBA to use in an SQL query, but that option is not available to SQL queries against an Access database from other applications (like your ASP app).

So, you will need to do the precise distance calculations in ASP after you retrieve the records that *might* qualify. That is, you could calculate the latitude and longitude boundaries of a 40km by 40km "square" centered on the target location (to exclude records that are guaranteed to be too far away), then calculate the actual distance for each of the returned records using your ASP function (example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4827479/2144390)).